# Print lines in file from the match line until end of file

Tags: sed

I wrote the following awk to print lines from the match line until EOF

```
awk '/match_line/,/*/' file
```

How can I do the same in sed?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
sed -n '/matched/,$p' file
awk '/matched/,0' file
```

Comment: Does `$` here means the end of the file, not end of the line?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez Yes `$` in sed means `end of file`

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez In sed `$` when used in the context of matching lines means EOF. When used within a regular expression, `$` still means EOL.

Answer (score 31):

This is for a really old version of GNU sed on Windows

GNU sed version 2.05

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

```
-n only display if Printed
-e expression to evaluate
d stands for Delete
p stands for Print
$ end of file
line1,line2 is the range
! is NOT
```

## haystack.txt

```
abc
def
ghi
needle
want 1
want 2
```

Print matching line and following lines to end of file

```
>sed.exe -n -e "/needle/,$p" haystack.txt
needle
want 1
want 2
```

Print start of file up to BUT NOT including matching line

```
>sed.exe -n -e "/needle/,$!p" haystack.txt
abc
def
ghi
```

Print start of file up to AND including matching line

```
>sed.exe -n -e "1,/needle/p" haystack.txt
abc
def
ghi
needle
```

Print everything after matching line

```
>sed.exe -n -e "1,/needle/!p" haystack.txt
want 1
want 2
```

Print everything between two matches - inclusive

```
>sed.exe -n -e "/def/,/want 1/p" haystack.txt
def
ghi
needle
want 1
```

Delete everything between two matches, no -n with this usage

```
>sed.exe -e "/ghi/,/want 1/d" haystack.txt
abc
def
want 2
```

Comment: Thanks: better explanation than the checked one. FWIW, another example (that unfortunately won't format multiline :-(

`# show global/file attributes of some compressed netCDF files`
`DIR='/asm/ROMO/cdc/2008cdc/smoke_out/2008ab_08c/12US1/cmaq_cb05_soa/'`
`FN='emis_mole_all_2008*'`
`for GZ in $(find "${DIR}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${FN}" | sort) ; do`
`echo -e "Processing ${GZ}, start=$(date)"`
`GZ_FN="$(basename ${GZ})"`
`NETCDF_FN="${GZ_FN%.gz}"`
`cp ${GZ} ./`
`gunzip ./${GZ_FN}`
`ncdump -h ./${NETCDF_FN} | sed -ne '/global attributes/,$p'`
`echo # newline between files`
`done`

Comment: What is if you want to print between 'def' and 'want 1'?

Comment: @ikwyl6 - I added another sample at the end that answers your question.