# How do I ignore all output of a bash command until a given marker

Tags: xcode, bash, shell, xcodebuild

I am running an `xcodebuild` command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace \
           -scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME_NAME" \
           -archivePath $ARCHIVE_PATH \
           -destination "$TEST_DESTINATION_DEVICE" \
           test
```

This produces lots of un-intesting output which I can filter using something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9566163/296446) `xcodebuild | egrep -A 5 "(error|warning):"`

However, I am interested in *all* of the test output.  The test output comes after this line:

```
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2014-09-29 14:04:54 +0000
```

So Is there a way to grep or filter everything after the above line? Preferable so that the error warning filter is preserved, i.e. Show the line if:

- Either the line contains "error" or "warning"
- Or the line is after the `'Test Suite * started at*'` line

Comment: Check [Print lines in file from the match line until end of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434462/)

Comment: @fedorqui - This looks good, would I pipe the output to a file and then `sed` it?

Comment: You can directly pipe the command to `sed`, as these good answers mention. Note also that some of your output can be `stderr`, in such case you have to [redirect it to `stdin`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another choice:

```
xcodebuild ... | sed '1,/^Test Suite/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
xcodebuild ... | awk -v print_me=0 '/^Test Suite/ { print_me=1 }; print_me { print };'
```

Initially, `print_me` has a false value, so the bare `print` rule will not be executed. Once a line matching the "Test Suite started" line is seen, the value of `print_me` switches to a true value, and the `print` rule will be executed for each line from then on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) I am getting many errors now labeled `stream error: stream error at offset 29: created by an unsupported XCDependencyGraph build`, any ideas?

Comment: @Robert, those errors have *nothing* to do with this answer.

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to define `print_me`. The default value of variable in awk is 0 (or null, or whatever), so `print_me {print}` would work. Also, `print_me` alone does the same, because the default behaviour of awk is `{print $0}`.

Comment: I used the explicit `{ print }` action to avoid having to explain the default action, but I missed that I could omit the `-v print_me=0`.

Comment: @glennjackman - Yes you are right, I think that output was from the `stderr` output.

Answer (score 1):

```
xcodebuild ... | grep -A 999999999 "search string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
xcodebuild ... | awk '/^Test Suite/{test=1; next}test'
```