# Print lines from match until end of file with awk

Tags: regex, awk

In [Print lines in file from the match line until end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434462/1983854) I learnt that you can use `0` in range expressions in `awk` to match until the end of the file:

```
awk '/matched/,0' file
```

However, today I started playing around this `0` and I found that this also works:

```
awk '/matched/,/!./' file
```

I guess `0` is working because in the range expression `/regex1/,/regex2/` the lines are printed until the `regex2` evaluates as True. And since `0` evaluates as False, this never happens and it ends up printing all the lines. Is this right?

However, with `/!./` I would imagine this to work until a line without any character is found, like if we said `awk '/matched/,!NF'`. But it does not: instead, it always evaluates to False. What is the reasons for this?

#### Examples

```
$ cat a
1
matched
2

3
4
end
```

Both `awk '/matched/,/!./' a` and `awk '/matched/,0' a` return:

```
matched
2

3
4
end
```

Whereas `awk '/matched/,!NF' a` returns:

```
matched
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have exclamation at wrong place. Keep it outside the regex like this to **negate the match**:

```
awk '/matched/,!/./' a
```

```
matched
2
```

---

Your regex `/!./` is matching a literal `!` followed by any character.

If your file is this:

```
cat a
1
matched
2

3
!4
end
```

Then

```
awk '/matched/,/!./' a
matched
2

3
!4
```

And:

```
awk '/matched/,!/./' a
```

```
matched
2
```

Comment: Oh! And what does `/!./` mean then?

Comment: That is matching `!` literally in regex followed by any character.

Comment: Haha it's right! I just tried adding `hello!bye` somewhere after `match` and it prints until that point. Many thanks :) As per the range expression, I am right on saying "in the range expression /regex1/,/regex2/ the lines are printed until the regex2 evaluates as True."?

Comment: Yes that is absolutely right. It prints until `/regex2/` is found or EOF is reached.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete answer. I am also glad to mark your answer as accepted for the first time after all this time being around knowledge :)

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, I must add here that I have learnt many new things from your answers on SO.