# What does the 0 mean in awk '/matched/,0' file?

Tags: awk

I recently came across the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434563/391161) which was very useful but gave no context about why the commands worked.

```
awk '/matched/,0' file
```

**What does the `0` mean in the context of this `awk` command?**

To expand on this, I'd like to understand if the literal string `0` has some special meaning in the context of the comma operator, and whether it has special meaning in other places in `awk`.

For example, `awk '/matched/,1' file` seems to have the same behavior as `awk '/matched/' file`, which is just to match lines that have `matched` in them.

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) I found seems to make no mention of `0` when used as a substitute for a pattern.

Comment: Isn't the title self-explanatory? "*Print lines in file from the match line until end of file*". `0` makes the range until the end of file.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I'd like a little more context or a link to documentation. A search for the comma operator in awk did not turn up anything.
If `0` means end of file, what does `1` or `-1` mean? The only documented way I know of doing this is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372108/34334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<condition 1>,<condition 2>` in awk and other tools is a "range expression" which means "match the set of lines starting when `condition 1` is true and ending when `condition 2` is true".

`0` is a false condition so it's never true so that block of lines continues til the end of the file.

Your specific range expression is:

`/matched/,0`

which is awk shorthand for:

match the lines starting when the condition `$0 ~ /matched/` is true and ending when the condition `0` is true (i.e. never so the end of the file).

Don't ever use range expressions, they make trivial tasks slightly briefer than using a flag but then anything slightly more interesting requires a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions. See [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/1745001) for details.

Comment: Is this knowledge that you happened to know, or is it documented somewhere that these are conditions rather than just patterns?

Comment: There's no such thing as a pattern (yes, I know all the awk books, etc. use that term but they're wrong). An awk script is made up of `<condition> { <action> }` segments. A condition can be a keyword like BEGIN, or a test against a regexp like `/a.*b/` or `$0 ~ /a.*b/`, or a string comparison like `$0 == "foo"`, or a hard-coded value like 0 for false or non-zero for true. But it doesn't matter - nowhere in there is the word "pattern" used and it's all just testing conditions just like inside an `if (<condition>) { <action> }` statement.

Comment: [GNU Awk User Guide on ranges](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html#Ranges)

Comment: @merlin2011, yes please it is documented, I just posted a small snippet of it too, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Though Ed Sir has explained it well about condition is FALSE, adding it with an example here.

Let's say we have following Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
test test test test test
test test test test test
>Cluster 145
0       4772nt, >CL1798.Contig5_All... at +/98.49%
1       4782nt, >CL1798.Contig8_All... *
2       4781nt, >CL1798.Contig10_All... at +/99.27%
3       4773nt, >CL1798.Contig11_All... at +/99.25%
```

Now we will try OP's given command:

```
awk '/>Cluster 145/,0' Input_file
>Cluster 145
0       4772nt, >CL1798.Contig5_All... at +/98.49%
1       4782nt, >CL1798.Contig8_All... *
2       4781nt, >CL1798.Contig10_All... at +/99.27%
3       4773nt, >CL1798.Contig11_All... at +/99.25%
```

***Now to make it more sense lets intentionally provide a FALSE condition which never gets TRUE in whole Input_file*** for example (where this is checking from a line which has string `/>Cluster 145/` to `singh`  but later string is never existing in Input_file:

```
awk '/>Cluster 145/,/singh/' Input_file
>Cluster 145
0       4772nt, >CL1798.Contig5_All... at +/98.49%
1       4782nt, >CL1798.Contig8_All... *
2       4781nt, >CL1798.Contig10_All... at +/99.27%
3       4773nt, >CL1798.Contig11_All... at +/99.25%
```

And we are seeing the same result what we got during mentioning `0` at end of the condition. So hence `0` means we are making condition FALSE which is never getting matched till END of Input_file and thus whole Input_file itself printing.

---

---

***From `gawk` documentation:*** See complete part in documentation about Range specification. For turning off the RANGE a pattern should be matched which is never happening in case of `/matced,0`, see highlighted.

```
awk '$1 == "on", $1 == "off"' myfile
```

> prints every record in myfile between ‘on’/‘off’ pairs, inclusive. A
>   range pattern starts out by matching begpat against every input
>   record. When a record matches begpat, the range pattern is turned on,
>   and the range pattern matches this record as well. **As long as the**
>   **range pattern stays turned on, it automatically matches every input**
>   **record read. The range pattern also matches endpat against every input**
>   **record; when this succeeds, the range pattern is turned off again for**
>   **the following record. Then the range pattern goes back to checking**
>   **begpat against each record.**